# Why can we use "die" in the present progressive tense?

Tags: grammar

> "Ask her to wait a moment - I am almost done. "  Carl Friedrich Gauss
>   (1777-1855),  while working, when informed that his wife is dying.

Why can we use "die" in the present progressive tense?

Comment: This is General Reference. ["We are dying from the moment we are born"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22We+are+dying+from+the+moment+we+are+born%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is not exactly an unknown sentiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is based on the assumption that verbs in progressive tenses must denote actions that have 'intermediate' or 'middle' states.  But this is not true.  The following are examples of verbs in progressive tenses that, like 'dying', do not describe an action that can be thought of as accumulating or proceeding little by little:

The clock is striking midnight.

As we speak, a nuclear bomb is going off in an underground test facility.

"What is he doing?"
"He is breaking the car window."

Comment: You are so smart to interpret what in my head was. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The use of present tense in historical narrative is very common. It is known as the [*historical present*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present). (*Wikipedia*)